# Deserialize text/plain after making request with restTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, deserialization, resttemplate

I'm trying to integrate my app with ebay Finding API, after getting familiar with api, I tried making some requests to see if it's working as expected, but one thing got me stuck. The ebay service even though I explicitly set RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT to JSON, returns response in json format but the content-type is text/plain. I set my restTemplate message converters as follows:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper)
{
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    messageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(
        ImmutableList
            .of(
                new MediaType("application", "json", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET),
                new MediaType("text", "plain", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
               ));

    return messageConverter;
}

@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Collections.singletonList(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter));
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Even though when I try to deserialize response which looks like this:
[json data](https://pastebin.com/M1cAgqax)

And object:

```
public class Response
{
   private String version;

   public Response()
   {
   }

   public String getVersion()
   {
      return version;
   }

   public void setVersion(String version)
   {
      this.version = version;
   }
}
```

My Api call:

```
String url = uriBuilder.formEndpoint("iphone").toString();
Response response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Response.class);
```

Is finishing with exception like this:

```
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for 
response type [class com.domain.Response] 
and content type [text/plain;charset=UTF-8]
```